# Activar Select Box segun checkbox seleccionado

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, table

Teniendo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que los select box Centro Costo, esten disabled y que se activen solo cuando el checkbox de su  sea clickeado independiente de que el usuario elija o no una opcion al habilitarse el select box.

```
<form method="post" id="form">
 <table id="listado" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th><i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp;SEL</th>
     <th>N° SOL</th>
     <th>FOLIO</th>
     <th>PRODUCTO</th>
     <th>CANT.</th>
     <th>CENTRO COSTO</th>
     <th>AUTORIZADO POR</th>
     <th>F. SOLICITUD</th>
     <th>F. AUTORIZACION</th>
     <th>ESTADO INTERNO</th>
     <th>ESTADO GENERAL</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <?php
     $conexion->set_charset("utf8");
     $consulta = "SELECT

      sm.id AS id_sol,
      sm.correlativo,
      sm.ids,
      sb.id AS id_sb,
      tr.nombre AS autorizado_por,
      sb.fecha_sol,
      sm.fecha_autorizacion,
      sm.producto,
      sm.cantidad,
      sb.estado

      FROM sol_maestranza sm

      INNER JOIN trabajadores tr ON tr.id = sm.autorizado_por
      LEFT JOIN salida_bodega sb ON sb.id = sm.ids

      WHERE sb.id_cl = '$id_cl' AND sb.estado = 'E' AND sm.estado_sol = 'S';
      $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
      if ($resultado->num_rows > 0){
       while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array()) {
        if($row['estado'] == 'E'){
         $est_int = "APROBADO";
        }else{
         $est_int = 'EN ESPERA';
        }
       ?>
       <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="sel[]" class="flat-red" value="<?=$row['id_sol']?>" ></td>
        <td><?=$row['ids']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['correlativo']; ?></td>
        <td><?=strtoupper($row['producto'])?></td>
        <td><?=$row['cantidad']; ?></td>
        <td width="13%">
         <select class="form-control" style="margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; width:100%" name="cci[]" required >
          <option value='' selected='selected' disabled>SELECCIONE OPCION</option>
          <?php foreach (array_combine($id_c, $nom_c) as $val1 => $val2){?>
          <option value="<?=$val1?>"><?=strtoupper($val2)?></option>
          <?php } ?>
          </select>
          </td>
          <td><?=strtoupper($row['autorizado_por']) ?></td>
          <td><?=DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$row['fecha_sol'])->format('d/m/Y')?></td>
          <td><?=DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$row['fecha_sol'])->format('d/m/Y')?></td>
          <td><?=$est_int ?></td>
          <td><?=$est_int?></td>
         </tr>
        <?php } } ?>

       </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3 class="box-title"><a href="myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success" data-target="#finaliza">CREAR ORDEN DE COMPRA</a></h3>
       </div>

    </form>
```

El como los envio (A una ventana Modal):

```
$('#finaliza').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

var $modal = $(this);

$.ajax({
 cache: false,
 type: 'POST',
 url: 'finaliza_oc.php',
 data: {'sel': JSON.stringify($('[name="sel[]"]').serializeArray()), 'cci': JSON.stringify($('[name="cci[]"]').serializeArray())
},
success: function(data) {
 $modal.find('.edit-content').html(data);
}
});
})
```

Y los recibo y proceso asi:

```
$obj = json_decode($_POST["sel"],true);
//PARA LOS IDS DE LOS CHEXKBOX SELECCIONADOS
foreach ($obj as $k){
 echo $k['value']; echo "<br>";
}

//PARA LOS SELECT BOX SELECCIONADOS
$obj = json_decode($_POST["cci"],true);

foreach ($obj as $k){
 echo $k['value']; echo "<br>";
}
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda u orientacion al respecto.
Saludos.

Comment: ¿Cómo estás recibiendo los valores en `finaliza_oc.php`? Por otra parte, el `select` para centro de costo no tiene nombre ni lo estás agregando en la petición AJAX.

Comment: Hola. creo que no se están asignando correctamente los nombres a los inputs en la línea `<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="sel[]" class="flat-red" value="<?=$row['id_sol']?>"` prueba a incluir los ids dentro del atributo name así: `name="sel[<?=$row['id_sol']?>]"`. Adicionalmente debe haber nombres calificados para los elementos select que van a enviar datos.

Comment: @quevedo gracias por responder. edite el problema en mi pregunta. mi problema son los select opcions, no los checkbox, ya que esos los puedo enviar y recibir de manera correcta.

Comment: En tu `data: { ... } ` no hay referencia a los elementos **select** de modo que cabe esperar que no los estés enviando para ser procesados. Por esa razón pensé que tenías problema con los input.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes saber es que cada item debe ter un id que se proporciona al desplegar los datos desde la consulta en php  es decir  algo como esto

```
<input  value="<?php echo $persona["id"];?>"  id="id-<?php echo $persona["id"];?>">
```

y el el ajax identificar al dar click ese id de esta forma

```
<script>
       $("#id-"+<?php echo $persona["id"];?>).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
id = document.getElementById("id-"+<?php echo $persona["id"];?>).value//obtener valor del input o del select dinamico
                               
                                       var url = "enviar-id.php";
                                       $.ajax({
                                          type: "POST",
                                          url: url,
                                         
                                          data:{id:id},
                                          success: function(data)
                                 {
                                                                     
                                 var datos = (data);
                                                                
                                if (data == "ok") { }
                                                                            
                                if (data == "no") { } 
                                     
                              }
                           });

                               });
</script>
```

pero todo eso debe ir dentro del while para asi poder asignarle un id dinámico a la tabla

```
 while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array()) {
```

Comment: estimado, gracias por responder. Edite el problema real en mi pregunta. El problema son los select opcions. Solo me envia el valor del primer select. Los checkbox los puedo enviar y recibir correctamente. Saludos.

Comment: Como te mostre en la respuesta debe haber un id dinamico para poder identificarlo y  enviarlo por ajax        <select class="form-control"  id="<?$row['id']?>" required>

Comment: perfecto. hare los cambios y las pruebas. comento cualquier novedad. saludos

Comment: vale recuerda que para que los id de el select sea diferente de otro id debes darlo un identificador adicional es decir      id="<?echo 'select'.$row['id']?>"

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de enviar los *checkbox* con `JSON.stringify($('[name="sel[]"]').serializeArray()` es necesario obtener todos los que están marcados e irlos agregando a un arreglo simple, solo con sus valores. Esto también servirá para buscar el valor de los *select*, asegurar que se seleccionó una opción y agregarlos también a su respectivo arreglo.

```
$('#finaliza').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  // ¿Qué uso le das a estas dos variables?
  var $modal = $(this),
  idp = e.relatedTarget.id;

  // Inicializar arreglos para checkbox y select
  let ids = [];
  let sels = [];
  let incompleto = false;

  // Recorrer solo los checkbox marcados
  $('[name="sel[]"]:checked').each(function(i, chk) {
    // Agregar ID del checkbox
    ids.push($(chk).val());
    // Obtener valor del select:
    // -- A partir del checkbox obtener la fila
    // -- Desde la fila, buscar select por etiqueta (no tiene nombre)
    let value = parseInt($(chk).closest('tr').find('select').val());
    if(value) {
      // Agregar valor del select
      sels.push(value);
    } else {
      incompleto = true;
    }
  });
  console.log(ids, sels);
  if(incompleto) {
      // El select es requerido, no puede tener valor cero
      alert('Selecciona centro de costo para todas las filas marcadas');
      return false;
  }

  $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'finaliza_oc.php',
    data: {
      'ids': JSON.stringify(ids),
      'sels': JSON.stringify(sels)
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $modal.find('.edit-content').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

En PHP los recibirás en dos arreglos:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
// ids => array(id1, id2, ... idX);
// sels => array(sel1, sel2, ... selX);
```

```js
$("#probar").on('click', function() {
  // Inicializar arreglos para checkbox y select
  let ids = [];
  let sels = [];
  let incompleto = false;

  // Recorrer solo los checkbox marcados
  $('[name="sel[]"]:checked').each(function(i, chk) {
    // Agregar ID del checkbox
    ids.push($(chk).val());
    // Obtener valor del select:
    // -- A partir del checkbox obtener la fila
    // -- Desde la fila, buscar select por etiqueta (no tiene nombre)
    let value = parseInt($(chk).closest('tr').find('select').val());
    if(value) {
      // Agregar valor del select
      sels.push(value);
    } else {
      incompleto = true;
    }
  });
  console.log(ids, sels);
  if(incompleto) {
      // El select es requerido, no puede tener valor cero
      alert('Selecciona centro de costo para todas las filas marcadas');
      return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="sel[]" class="flat-red" value="1"></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Producto 1</td>
        <td><select class="form-control" name="cci[]" required >
          <option value='' selected='selected' disabled>SELECCIONE OPCION</option>
          <option value="1">Centro 1</option>
          <option value="2">Centro 2</option>
        </select></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="sel[]" class="flat-red" value="2"></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Producto 2</td>
        <td><select class="form-control" name="cci[]" required >
          <option value='' selected='selected' disabled>SELECCIONE OPCION</option>
          <option value="1">Centro 1</option>
          <option value="2">Centro 2</option>
        </select></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="sel[]" class="flat-red" value="3"></td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Producto 3</td>
        <td><select class="form-control" name="cci[]" required >
          <option value='' selected='selected' disabled>SELECCIONE OPCION</option>
          <option value="1">Centro 1</option>
          <option value="2">Centro 2</option>
        </select></td>
      </tr>
</table>
<button id="probar">Probar</button>
```

Comment: estimado, gracias por responder. Revisando tu respuesta, quiero preguntar algunas cosas. Los ids corresponden solo a un dato anexo (sin mayor importancia para el usuario). Siendo asi y para entender tu solucion, lo estas anexando solo para crear el array correspondiente? Ya que los valores que realmente necesito son sel[] y los centros de costo. Agradeceria me aclares esa duda por favor. Saludos y gracias

Comment: Haciendo algunas pruebas con tu respuesta, me da el suguiente error:

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).value is not a function

Comment: estimado, si bien he logrado enviar los checkbox y los select, el codigo que me enviaste para la "validacion" de los select segun check seleccionado, no funciona. Activo 1 o 2 check y se envia igual sin hacer la validacion de los select (name="cci"). Que podria ser, ya que ahora que puedo enviar y recibir los datos, necesito validar que se seleccione el centro de costo segun chek seleccionado. Gracias por tu ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Oka, lo hare y te comento.

Comment: Listo estimado, acabo de editar la pregunta. No puse el codigo que me enviaste para mostrar de forma limpia lo que tengo por ahora. Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Hace lo mismo que antes, no valida nada. A que te refieres con los posibles valores.. reales.. del select?

Comment: hice lo que me comentaste, no muestra valor alguno en la consola. estaba pensando que quiza la mejor solucion sea dejar todos los select deshabilitados y cuando se active un checkbox se habilite el select. si el usuario lo elige, se guardara con ese valor, de lo contrario lo guardara sin centro de costo.. que opinas?

Comment: Listo, prueba ahora